# VLANs: No Internet Access

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, cisco-asa, firewall

I've set up a new VLAN (VLAN 11) to service subnet `10.0.11.0\24`. It's primarily for wired PCs. I have DHCP working. I can browse all of my network, file shares, ping interfaces etc. I can't get my new VLAN devices out onto the Internet, or communicating with `192.168.2.0/24` which is connected site-to-site VPN. Where have I gone wrong?

Note: I do all my firewall config through ASDM. I find CLI on the ASA confusing.

**Hardware Used:**

- Firewall - Cisco ASA 5510
- Core Switch - Dell Force10 50s Stacked
- DHCP - Windows Server 2008R2 (VM)

**Switch Config (Relevant Parts):**

```
interface GigabitEthernet 1/1
 description Uplink to Cisco ASA5510
 no ip address
 portmode hybrid
 switchport
 no shutdown
```

sh vlan

```
NUM    Status    Description                     Q Ports
1      Active                                    U Gi 0/1-23,25-43
                                                 U Gi 1/1-44
10     Active                                    T Gi 0/1,44
                                                 T Gi 1/1
11     Active                                    T Gi 0/1
                                                 U Gi 0/24
                                                 T Gi 1/1
```

sh ip int br

```
Vlan 1                   192.168.1.230   YES Manual up                    up
Vlan 10                  10.0.10.251     YES Manual up                    up
Vlan 11                  10.0.11.251     YES Manual up                    up
```

sh ip route

```
       Destination        Gateway                      Dist/Metric Last Change
       -----------        -------                      ----------- -----------
 *S    0.0.0.0/0          via 192.168.1.250, Vl 1              1/0       81w5d
  C    10.0.10.0/24       Direct, Vl 10                        0/0        4d6h
  C    10.0.11.0/24       Direct, Vl 11                        0/0       2d23h
  C    192.168.1.0/24     Direct, Vl 1                         0/0       81w5d
```

**Firewall Config:**

```
sh run 
: Saved
: 
: Serial Number: *****
: Hardware:   ASA5510, 1024 MB RAM, CPU Pentium 4 Celeron 1600 MHz
:
ASA Version 9.1(6) 
!
hostname LDHQFW
enable password 6OKb.d/KJtTCYuU9 encrypted
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd 2KFQnbNIdI.2KYOU encrypted
names
ip local pool VPN 10.1.11.1-10.1.11.254 mask 255.255.255.0
ip local pool AC-10 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.50 mask 255.255.255.0
ip local pool 172.16.10.0 172.16.10.1-172.16.10.200 mask 255.255.255.0


!
interface Ethernet0/0
 nameif Outside
 security-level 0
 ip address x.x.x.185 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 nameif Inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.171 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Ethernet0/1.10
 description HQ_Servers
 vlan 10
 nameif VLAN_10
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.10.252 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Ethernet0/1.11
 description HQ_PCs
 vlan 11
 nameif VLAN_11
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.11.252 255.255.255.0 


!
interface Ethernet0/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 shutdown
 nameif Management
 security-level 100
 no ip address
!
boot system disk0:/asa916-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa915-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa913-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa912-k8.bin
ftp mode passive


clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns domain-lookup Inside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 192.168.1.221
 name-server 192.168.1.225
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network 192.168.0.0_24
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
object network 192.168.1.0_24
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network 192.168.2.0_24
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
 description MFG
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network 192.168.1.96_27
 subnet 192.168.1.96 255.255.255.224
object network myvpn
 subnet 10.1.11.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.1.11.0_24
 subnet 10.1.11.0 255.255.255.0
object network insidenat


 subnet 10.250.250.0 255.255.255.0
object network ComcastGateway
 host x.x.x.x
object network 192.168.6.0_24
 subnet 192.168.6.0 255.255.255.0
object network LDHQFS_FTPServer
 host 192.168.1.227
object network FTPServer_ext
 host x.x.x.186
object service FTP2
 service tcp source range 1 65535 destination eq 35262 
object network LDHQWS_Internal
 host 192.168.1.226
object network LDHQEC_EXT
 host x.x.x.187
object service RDP
 service tcp source range 1 65535 destination eq 3389 
object network RouterVLAN2
 host 192.168.0.2
object network MFG_Inside-Network
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
object network 192.168.50.0_24
 subnet 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0
object network LDHQSQL


 host 192.168.1.222
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.0.0_26
 subnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.192
object service ftp_ssl_tls
 service tcp source range 1 65535 destination eq 990 
 description implicit ftp
object service ftp_passive
 service tcp source range 1 65535 destination range 51200 51300 
object network LDHQEC_INT
 host 192.168.1.228
object network LDHQUB_INT
 host 192.168.1.218
 description Ubuntu Server Interior IP Address
object network LDHQUB_EXT
 host x.x.x.188
 description External Ip Address
object network HQ_PCs
 subnet 10.0.11.0 255.255.255.0
 description HQ_PCs
object network HQ_Printers
 subnet 10.0.12.0 255.255.255.0
 description HQ_Printers
object network HQ_Servers
 subnet 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0


 description HQ_Servers
object network HQ_Wireless
 subnet 10.0.13.0 255.255.255.0
 description HQ_Wireless
object network VPN_IPs_172
 subnet 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0
 description VPN IP Address Pool 172.16.10.0\24
object network VPN_Public_IP
 host x.x.x.185
 description VPN Public Address
object network CoreSwitch_VLAN11
 host 10.0.11.251
object network Router_VLAN_11
 host 10.0.11.250
object-group network LDHQ
 description All Headquarters networks
 network-object object 192.168.0.0_24
 network-object object 192.168.1.0_24
 network-object object 192.168.2.0_24
 network-object object HQ_PCs
 network-object object HQ_Printers
 network-object object HQ_Servers
 network-object object HQ_Wireless
object-group service FTPPassive tcp


 port-object range 51200 51300
 port-object eq ftp
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_1 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service FTP_Ports tcp
 port-object range 51200 51300
 port-object eq 990
 port-object eq ftp
 port-object eq ftp-data
object-group network d90_home
 network-object 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.10.5.0 255.255.255.0
access-list Outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object LDHQFS_FTPServer object-group FTP_Ports 
access-list Outside_access_in extended permit ip object-group LDHQ any4 
access-list Outside_access_in extended permit icmp any4 any4 
access-list Outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object LDHQEC_INT object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_1 
access-list Outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object LDHQUB_INT eq www 
access-list Inside_access_in extended permit ip object-group LDHQ any4 
access-list HQ_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list LDHQ_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list LD_10_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list LD_10_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 10.1.11.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list crypto_allowmyvpnaccess extended permit ip object myvpn object insidenat 


access-list LD_6_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list LD_6_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list Outside_cryptomap extended permit ip object 192.168.1.0_24 object 192.168.2.0_24 
access-list Outside_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 object 192.168.2.0_24 
access-list LDCorp_MFG_Networks standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list LDCorp_MFG_Networks standard permit 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging timestamp
logging emblem
logging trap debugging
logging history debugging
logging asdm informational
logging facility 16
logging host Inside 192.168.1.226 format emblem
logging debug-trace
mtu Outside 1500
mtu Inside 1500
mtu VLAN_10 1500
mtu VLAN_11 1500
mtu Management 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-743.bin
no asdm history enable


arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (Inside,Inside) source dynamic any interface destination static LDHQUB_EXT LDHQUB_INT description U-Turn for Feedback.mydomain.com
nat (Inside,Inside) source dynamic any interface destination static LDHQEC_EXT LDHQEC_INT description U-Turn for enterprise\parts.mydomain.com
nat (Inside,Outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 inactive
nat (Inside,Outside) source static LDHQ LDHQ destination static 192.168.1.96_27 192.168.1.96_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup inactive
nat (Outside,Inside) source static myvpn myvpn destination static insidenat insidenat inactive
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.0_24 192.168.1.0_24 destination static 192.168.6.0_24 192.168.6.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup inactive
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.2.0_24 192.168.2.0_24 destination static 192.168.1.0_24 192.168.1.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.0_24 192.168.1.0_24 destination static 192.168.2.0_24 192.168.2.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (Outside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.0_24 192.168.1.0_24 destination static 192.168.1.96_27 192.168.1.96_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup inactive
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.0_24 192.168.1.0_24 destination static 192.168.1.96_27 192.168.1.96_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup inactive
nat (Inside,Outside) source static any any destination static 192.168.50.0_24 192.168.50.0_24 no-proxy-arp route-lookup inactive
nat (Inside,Outside) source static any any destination static VPN_IPs_172 VPN_IPs_172 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (Inside,Outside) source static LDHQ LDHQ destination static VPN_IPs_172 VPN_IPs_172 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (Outside,Inside) source static any any destination static LDHQEC_EXT LDHQEC_INT
nat (any,Inside) source static any any destination static LDHQUB_EXT LDHQUB_INT
nat (Inside,Outside) source static LDHQ LDHQ destination static d90_home d90_home no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network LDHQFS_FTPServer
 nat (Inside,Outside) static FTPServer_ext
!
nat (Inside,Outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface


access-group Outside_access_in in interface Outside
access-group Inside_access_in in interface Management
route Outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 x.x.x.190 1 
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa-server AD protocol ldap
aaa-server AD (Inside) host 192.168.1.225
 server-port 389
 ldap-base-dn DC=LDI_NETWORK,DC=COM
 ldap-scope subtree
 ldap-login-password *****
 ldap-login-dn CN=CiscoVPN,CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=LDI_NETWORK,DC=COM
 server-type microsoft
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa local authentication attempts max-fail 5


http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Management
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Inside
http 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 Inside
http 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0 Inside
snmp-server host Inside 192.168.1.226 community ***** udp-port 514
snmp-server host-group Inside NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 poll community *****
snmp-server location LD HQ
snmp-server contact Nicholas Dininno
snmp-server community *****
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 


crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES


 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set pfs group1
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
crypto map Outside_map 10 match address Outside_cryptomap
crypto map Outside_map 10 set pfs 
crypto map Outside_map 10 set peer x.x.x.99 
crypto map Outside_map 10 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA
crypto map Outside_map 10 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES 3DES AES AES192 AES256
crypto map Outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map Outside_map interface Outside
crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
 no validation-usage
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 enrollment self


 subject-name CN=LDHQFW
 keypair LDAnyConnect
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint1
 enrollment terminal
 subject-name CN=work.mydomain.com,O=My Company Inc,C=US
 keypair VPN_1_8_2016_Req
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint3
 enrollment self
 subject-name CN=192.168.1.171
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable Outside client-services port 443
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint1
crypto ikev1 enable Outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes


 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des


 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des


 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Inside
telnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Management
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Outside
ssh 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
management-access Inside
vpn-addr-assign local reuse-delay 10
dhcpd auto_config Inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics host
threat-detection statistics port
threat-detection statistics protocol
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ntp server 192.168.1.250 source Inside
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint1 Outside


ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint3 Inside
webvpn
 enable Outside
 anyconnect-essentials
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.05170-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-macosx-i386-3.1.04074-k9.pkg 2
 anyconnect profiles AC_LDVPN_client_profile disk0:/AC_LDVPN_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect profiles AnyConnect_client_profile disk0:/AnyConnect_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 ssl-clientless
group-policy GroupPolicy_AC_LDVPN internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_AC_LDVPN attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server value 192.168.1.225 192.168.1.221
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 ssl-client 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value LDCorp_MFG_Networks
 default-domain none
 webvpn
  anyconnect profiles value AC_LDVPN_client_profile type user
group-policy GroupPolicy_x.x.x.99 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_x.x.x.99 attributes


 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 
group-policy HQ internal
group-policy HQ attributes
 dns-server value 192.168.1.220 192.168.1.221
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-client 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value LD_6_splitTunnelAcl
username ******* password ******** encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group HQ type remote-access
tunnel-group HQ general-attributes
 address-pool 172.16.10.0
 authentication-server-group AD
 default-group-policy HQ
tunnel-group HQ ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group x.x.x.99 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group x.x.x.99 general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_x.x.x.99
tunnel-group x.x.x.99 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group AC_LDVPN type remote-access
tunnel-group AC_LDVPN general-attributes


 address-pool 172.16.10.0
 authentication-server-group AD
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_AC_LDVPN
tunnel-group AC_LDVPN webvpn-attributes
 group-alias AC_LDVPN enable
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 


  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
 class class-default
  user-statistics accounting
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
service call-home
call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 contact-email-addr me@mydomain.com
 contact-name Nicholas
 phone-number 732-474-8723
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment


  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:xxxxx
: end

LDHQFW#
```

[image: Network Diagram]

[image: Updated Network Diagram]

Comment: Your network and configs are a mess. Who's doing the routing, the switch, the router, or the firewall -- both have addresses in every network.

Comment: You have a lot of references to `10.1.11.0 255.255.255.0` in the ASA, but VLAN 11 is `10.0.11.0 255.255.255.0`. Is this correct?

Comment: @rickyBeam the router has been removed from my environment. Routing is going to happen on the firewall.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes you are correct.

Comment: There are several tasks required to get connectivity through the Cisco ASA up.  It sounds like routing/layer3 is an issue, could be NAT/PAT issue, also a VPN issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers route between networks. You don't route from one network to the same network: This is probably your problem:

```
ip route 10.0.11.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.11.251
```

All your other routes are to `192.168.1.171`, a hop on a different network (the firewall inside interface):

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.171
ip route 10.0.11.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.11.251
ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.171
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.171
!
```

You can try this:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.171
ip route 10.0.11.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.171
ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.171
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.171
!
```

**Edit:**

I guess I don't understand the purpose of the Cisco 1921 router. You are routing the same networks on both the 1921 and the ASA. It looks like you are using the ASA as the DHCP server.

You could remove the 1921 and change DHCP to point the gateways to the ASA itself. Alternatively, you could move DHCP to the 1921 and remove the VLANs from the ASA. In either case, you only need the VLANs on one of the devices, and have the `192.168.1.0/24` link between them (you don't need to use a `/24` because a `/31` or, more traditionally, a `/30`).

Using static routing, as you have configured, doesn't scale, and, as you have discovered, causes you to manually make changes, which increases the possibility of problems or errors.

If you want both the router and the ASA, you can use OSPF to exchange routes. The ASA would the inject the default route into OSPF, and the 1921 would inject the VLAN routes into OSPF. Each device would automatically learn the routes from the other device through OSPF.

Based on what you have, I would just eliminate the Cisco 1921 router, and change the gateways provided by the ASA. You would need to make the VLAN interfaces on the ASA be inside interfaces.

Comment: Ron, thank you for taking the time to address my issue. I made the change you recommended, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: A network diagram will help. You can edit your question to provide one. I have to run, but I will look at this later.

Comment: OK. network diagram added. LMK if i'm missing anything else.

Comment: ASA is not the DHCP server. It only does DHCP for vpn clients. DHCP is done on a windows server for all internal networks. The router was originally for an mpls line but that got scrapped in lieu of a vpn tunnel and cable internet for our sattelite office (way more cost effective and 'stable enough'). Now the 1921 is really only for inter VLAN routing. Based on your last paragraph,  do you think i should use the firewall as my DG in DHCP or the core switch?

Comment: Then I really don't understand the reason for the VLAN interfaces on the ASA. I really think the router is gratuitous. If the switch is a layer-3 switch, that would be the gateways and do the inter-VLAN routing. It should then connect to the ASA with a layer-3 routed link, not a layer-2 VLAN. I can see how this developed over time, but it looks like it is past time to redesign, simplify, and optimize it.

Comment: OK, so I'm totally on board with doing this. I'm just not sure how to accomplish considering my limited experience. I went ahead and change the gateway on my core swithch to the inside interface IP of the ASA. I also shut the port going to the router. InterVLAN routing is now broken (which isnt a big deal yet).  I could use your help getting the switch to do that routing.

Answer (score 1):

For Internet access you will need a new nat rule on the asa, something like

> Nat (vlan_11, outside) ...

For the vpn to work you need to add the 10.0.11.0 subnet to the cryptomap_outside acl, and also to the crypto acl on the vpn peer .

Apologies for the brief answer, typing this on my phone. Will be glad to expand later if needed.